# Which video formats are supported to set as Windows 8 User Account picture?

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 8, users are allowed to capture a short video using webcam and use the video as the user account picture. I want to know what format is that video in, so I can override it with my custom video. I do not have a webcam so I cannot test it myself. I have tried .avi and .wmv but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this guide](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/13679/windows-8-how-to-use-a-video-as-a-user-tile/)

1. Prepare your clip. The file should be in WMV format (others may work as well), less than 10 seconds in length. The video resolution in this example is at 240×180.
2. Go to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Default Pictures`

   1. Paste your clip there
   2. Rename it to the following format: usertile`x`.ms-usertiledynamic
      (replace x with a number).
3. Click on your User Tile, go to My Look.
4. Choose the video and hit OK.
5. The video will only be played when users click on the User Tile.

The guide contain additional tricks like using a bitmap and video as User Tile at the same time

**Note:** I tried using the browse function on my own PC, but it cannot open any video formats I know of. MP4, MPG, M4V, WMV or AVI. WMV would be the most logical choice for Windows, since it's named Windows Media Video

Comment: I inserted a summary of your source. Also the source article doesn't mention a software to prepare a clip, or?

Comment: He doesn't mention it, but it's obviously not a standard application he has lying in the corner. It seems he's using an application named Sicaism

Comment: Erm, isn't this the user account's name?